# Handling Encoding Errors in a UTF-8 File with Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I'm trying to use a corpus for training an ML model but I'm running into some encoding errors that where likely caused by someone else's conversion/annotation of the file. I can visually see the errors when opening the file in `vim` but python doesn't seem to notice them when reading.  The corpus is fairly large so I need to find a way to get python to detect them and hopefully a method to correct them.

Here's a sample line as viewed in `vim`...

`# ::snt That<92>s what we<92>re with<85>You<92>re not sittin<92> there in a back alley and sayin<92> hey what do you say, five bucks?`

The <92> should be an apostrophe and the <85> should probably be 3 dots.  There are a number of other values that appear on other lines.  Doing some googling, I'm thinking the original encoding was probably CP1252 but currently the `file` command under Linux list this file as UTF-8.  I've tried a few ways to open this but no luck...

`with open(fn) as f:` returns

`# ::snt Thats what were withYoure not sittin there in a back alley and sayin hey what do you say, five bucks?`

which is skipping those tokens and concatenating words, which is a problem.

`with open(fn, encoding='CP1252') as f:` returns

`# ::snt ThatA's what weA're withA...YouA're not sittinA' there in a back alley and sayinA' hey what do you say, five bucks?`

which is visually inserting "A" for those odd characters.

`with io.open(fn, errors='strict')` doesn't raise any errors and neither does reading in a byte stream and decoding, so unfortunately at this point I can't even detect the errors much less correct for them.

Is there a way to read in this large file and detect encoding errors within it.  Even better, is there a way to correct them?

Comment: You could try https://pypi.org/project/charset-normalizer/

Comment: That lib didn't seem to work and `unidecode` doesn't work either, although `unidecode` does at least strip the offending characters.

Comment: Are only *some* lines in cp1252?  Is the whole file cp1252?

Comment: I'm a little unclear what's going on.  Reading the file (or only the example line above) as CP1252 doesn't work correctly so I'm guessing the file is encoded with UTF-8 but has invalid characters in it that `vim` is able to detect but python is ignoring?

Comment: maybe you could put original file on Google Drive (or similar portal) so we could download original file and test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the original data from your answer, you've got mojibake from a double-encode.  You need a double-decode to translate it properly.

```
>>> s = b'# ::snt That\xc2\x92s what we\xc2\x92re with\xc2\x85You\xc2\x92re not sittin\xc2\x92 there in a back alley and sayin\xc2\x92 hey what do you say, five bucks?\n'
>>> s.decode('utf8').encode('latin1').decode('cp1252')
'# ::snt That’s what we’re with…You’re not sittin’ there in a back alley and sayin’ hey what do you say, five bucks?\n'
```

The data is actually in UTF-8, but on decode to Unicode the code points of the errors are the bytes for a `Windows-1252` code page.  The `.encode('latin1')` converts the Unicode code points 1:1 back to bytes, since the `latin1` encoding is the first 256 code points of Unicode, then it can be decoded correctly as Windows-1252.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workable but not very elegant solution...

```
# Read in file as a raw byte-string
fn  = 'bad_chars.txt'
with open(fn, 'rb') as f:
    text = f.read()
print(text)

# Detect out of range 
has_bad = False
for c in text:
    if c >= 128:
        has_bad = True
print('Had bad:', has_bad)

# Fix offending characters
text = text.replace(b'\xc2\x92', b"\x27")
text = text.replace(b'\xc2\x85', b"...")
text = text.decode('utf-8')
print(text)
```

Which produces the following output...

```
b'# ::snt That\xc2\x92s what we\xc2\x92re with\xc2\x85You\xc2\x92re not sittin\xc2\x92 there in a back alley and sayin\xc2\x92 hey what do you say, five bucks?\n'

Had bad: True

# ::snt That's what we're with...You're not sittin' there in a back alley and sayin' hey what do you say, five bucks?
```

The downside is I need to find the offending characters and code a `replace` command for this to work.  There is table of possible replacement codes found in a similar question at.. [efficiently replace bad characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609895/efficiently-replace-bad-characters).